# Interrupting a forever while-loop asynchronously with an input widget in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, jupyter-notebook, queue, ipywidgets

I want to interrupt a forever while-loop asynchronously with user input. To simulate this, I have written two functions. The first `myCounter()` counts down from a number, say 9. This could be a large number or while loop that runs forever. The other function takes a user input and terminates the first function's execution.

To get asynchronous behavior, I run each function in its own thread with a shared messaging queue between them. When the user signals termination, the second function puts the message on the queue and exits. The first function picks up the message in its next iteration and terminates execution.

This works with user input using Python's `input()` function but the same behavior is not achieved using an interactive input widget in Jupyter notebook. I am at a loss to understand why. The functions and code are below.

```
def myCounter(progressBar, q):
    for i in reversed(range(9)):
        ans = 0        # Initialize
        time.sleep(1)
        progressBar.value = (9-i)/9
        try:
            ans = q.get(block=False)
        except:
            q.put(-7)  # So queue isn't empty   
        if ans == 1:
            break      # Terminate this thread
    q.put(1)           # Let the other thread know

def mySemaphore(checkBox, q):
    while True:
        #ans = int(input("Tell me yes or no [1/0]: "))   # Works!
        ans = int(checkBox.value)                        # Doesn't :(
        print("Interrupt has {}".format(ans))
        if ans == 1:
            q.put(1)   # Signal termination ..
            break      # .. and exit.
        elif q.get() == 1:
            break      # Quit!
```

Run with:

```
dummy = -7
q = queue.LifoQueue()
q.put(dummy)

progressBar = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)
checkBox = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description="Continue?", disabled=False)

myFirstThread = threading.Thread(target=myCounter, args=(progressBar, q))
myNextThread = threading.Thread(target=mySemaphore, args=(checkBox, q))

display(progressBar)
display(checkBox)

myFirstThread.start()
myNextThread.start()

myFirstThread.join()
myNextThread.join()
```

The first function's progress is shown by a progress bar and the checkbox value is printed out. The value doesn't change when the checkbox is checked. I have tried using input widgets other than checkbox and making the checkbox local to the second function but none of these have worked. I appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: I tried to run your code removing the two `thread.join()` lines and I think it worked as expected?

Comment: @ac24 You are right, it works as expected after removing `thread.join()` operations. I thought the join operation returns control back to the main program after completion and it sounds like my understanding is incorrect. Thanks so much for the tip, I appreciate your help!